# Gitlab Services won't connect to Windows SQL Server Service

Tags: sql-server, gitlab-ci, docker-for-windows

I am trying to run integration tests on an app and for this I need to have both an IIS Server and an SQL Server so I am trying to run an SQL Server as a service.
I applied an alias to it, so I could know what is the host name but it just fails to connect regardless.

```
test installer:
  stage: Integration Test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis
  services:
  - name: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer:2017-latest
    alias: localhost_mssql
  variables:
    ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
    sa_password: 'Sa123456'
  tags: 
    - windows
  script:
    - "sqlcmd -S localhost_mssql -U sa -P Sa123456"
```

It can't locate the host:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

I've read some threads about how I should enable SQL Browser Service but not sure how to do that or why wouldn't it work out of the blue.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In case you were unaware... the SQL Server on Windows Containers beta program is effectively dead: [Update- Beta program for SQL Server on Windows container is suspended](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/update-beta-program-for-sql-server-on-windows-container-is/ba-p/2516639). You should consider using the supported [Microsoft SQL Server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) on Docker Linux containers instead.

Comment: Regardless of using SQL Server on Windows containers or Linux containers... the SQL Server service does not have sockets accepting client connections from the very microsecond a container starts. It goes through a process of verifying database files, rolling back transactions, and upgrading them to the latest file format before creating a socket that accepts connections. Depending on the number and size of database files this can take tens of seconds or more.

Comment: Microsoft's [Configure and customize SQL Server Docker containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-configure) contains a link to [twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app) which demonstrates how to have a script wait for the SQL Server service to start accepting connections before it carries out setup operations such as creating databases and tables and/or loading data. The demo is for Node, but the concepts apply to all languages.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I switched to linux, I even tried to set it up as the image instead of a service, nothing worked. I suspected that its really the case as you say with the time that it takes to go up. I'll try to follow your links hopefully there is a waiting loop there or something